# Undefined method Error message in Ruby 2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have zero experience with Ruby, and I'm having the following issue:
I receive a "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error message when I try to login into my admin panel (mydomain.com/administrator).

Checking the logs I found out the following:
[image: production log]

As well, I checked the login_controller.rb:
[image]

Here you have the template:

```
<h1><%= t(".title")%></h1>

<!-- Pages --> 
<% if @pages.length > 0 %> 
  <h3><%= t(".lastets_pages")%></h3> 
  <table>     
    <thead>     
      <tr>       
        <th>#</th>       
        <th><%=t("activerecord.attributes.page.title")%></th>       
        <th><%=t("activerecord.attributes.page.slug")%></th>       
        <th><%=t("generic.user_id")%></th>       
        <th><%=t("generic.created_at")%></th>       
        <th><%=t("generic.updated_at")%></th>       
        <th><%=t("generic.actions")%></th>     
      </tr>   
    </thead>   
    <tbody>     
      <% @pages.each do |page| %>     
        <tr>       
          <td><%= page.id %></td>       
          <td><%= page.title %></td>       
          <td><%= page.slug %></td>       
          <td><%= page.user.username %></td>       
          <td><%= l(page.created_at, format: :long) %></td>       
          <td><%= l(page.updated_at, format: :long) %></td>       
          <td class="actions_links">
            <%= link_to t("generic.edit"), edit_administrator_page_path(page) %>
            <%= link_to t("generic.delete"), administrator_page_path(page), :confirm => t("generic.delete_confirmation"), :method => :delete, class: "delete" %>       
          </td>     
        </tr>     
      <% end %>   
    </tbody> 
  </table> 
<% else %>   
  <h3><%= t(".lastets_pages")%></h3>   
  <div class="alert alert-warning">     <%= t(".lastets_pages_empty")%>   </div> 
<% end %>

<!-- Notices --> 
<% if @notices.length > 0 %>     
  <h3><%= t(".lastets_notices")%></h3>   
  <table>         
    <thead>       
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th><%=t("activerecord.attributes.notice.title")%></th>
        <th><%=t("activerecord.attributes.notice.countries")%></th>
        <th><%=t("activerecord.attributes.notice.slug")%></th>
        <th><%=t("generic.user_id")%></th>
        <th><%=t("generic.created_at")%></th>
        <th><%=t("generic.updated_at")%></th>
        <th><%=t("generic.actions")%></th>       
      </tr>     
    </thead>     
    <tbody>             
      <% @notices.each do |notice| %>       
        <tr>
          <td><%= notice.id %></td>
          <td><%= notice.title %></td>        
          <td><%= notice.show_countries %></td>
          <td><%= notice.slug %></td>
          <td><%= notice.user.username %></td>
          <td><%= l(notice.created_at, format: :long) %></td>
          <td><%= l(notice.updated_at, format: :long) %></td>
          <td class="actions_links">
            <%= link_to t("generic.edit"), edit_administrator_notice_path(notice) %>
            <%= link_to t("generic.delete"), administrator_notice_path(notice), :confirm => t("generic.delete_confirmation"), :method => :delete, class: "delete" %>
          </td>       
        </tr>       
      <% end %>     
    </tbody>   
  </table> 
<% else %>   
  <h3><%= t(".lastets_notices")%></h3>   
  <div class="alert alert-warning">     <%= t(".lastets_notices_empty")%>   </div> 
<% end %>

<!-- Faqs --> 
<% if @faqs.length > 0 %>   
  <h3><%= t(".lastets_faqs")%></h3>   
  <table>         
    <thead>       
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th><%=t("activerecord.attributes.faq.title")%></th>
        <th><%=t("activerecord.attributes.faq.slug")%></th>
        <th><%=t("generic.user_id")%></th>
        <th><%=t("generic.created_at")%></th>
        <th><%=t("generic.updated_at")%></th>
        <th><%=t("generic.actions")%></th>       
      </tr>     
    </thead>     
    <tbody>             
      <% @faqs.each do |faq| %>       
        <tr>
          <td><%= faq.id %></td>
          <td><%= faq.title %></td>
          <td><%= faq.slug %></td>
          <td><%= faq.user.username %></td>
          <td><%= l(faq.created_at, format: :long) %></td>
          <td><%= l(faq.updated_at, format: :long) %></td>
          <td class="actions_links">
            <%= link_to t("generic.edit"), edit_administrator_faq_path(faq) %>
            <%= link_to t("generic.delete"), administrator_faq_path(faq), :confirm => t("generic.delete_confirmation"), :method => :delete, class: "delete" %>
          </td>       
        </tr>       
      <% end %>     
    </tbody>   
  </table> 
<% else %>   
  <h3><%= t(".lastets_faqs")%></h3>   
  <div class="alert alert-warning">     <%= t(".lastets_faqs_empty")%>   </div> 
<% end %>
```

Notice.rb model:
[image: notice.rb model]

Can you help me to identify the issue? I tried to clear the cache and nothing happened.

Comment: That screenshot is difficult to read, you should post the contents of the template (/administrator/login/dashboard.html.erb) where the no method error is happening. It would also be helpful to see the user and notice models.

Comment: There you have it now, pdoherty926...

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't tell us anything helpful. What about the user model? Does `user#username` have a reference to `.name`?

Comment: The error is in `notice` model. Show its source.

Comment: Marek Lipka, there you have the notice.rb model

Comment: Could you paste text instead of screenshot?

Comment: I just edited your question to indent the template code properly.  Nice formatting (especially indentation) is very important if you want people to be able to understand your code rather than go "aargh wtf".

Comment: Thank you very much... I think here is the problem: countries << country_post.country.name

Comment: Your problem is that `@notices` contains some `nil` values, and you're expecting it to just contain Notice objects.  I can't see where `@notices` is being defined.  I'd expect to see it in your controller.  Also - why are you including screengrabs of your code?  Why not just copy the code?  if you make sure it has at least four spaces (or a double indent) at the start of each line then stackoverflow will display it properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support... I found out that there are several registers that were deleted and that's the reason that the values are nil...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error backtrace points to the `notice.rb:7` file, which is the line inside the block:

```
countries << country_post.country.name
```

`Undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` means you are trying to call `nil.name`, so for a given `country_post`, `country_post.country` returns `nil`.

You'll have to check this part of the code to solve the bug. Another thing you can do is use the `try` method:

```
countries << country_post.country.try(:name)
```

this `try` method will return `country.name` if `country` is not `nil, or`nil` otherwise:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cd2d3664e3b434d15b6c19e652befb386187642f/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L93
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cd2d3664e3b434d15b6c19e652befb386187642f/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L62

Answer (score 2):

In your Notice.rb model use:

**countries << country_post.country.try(:name)**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to use the `notice.show_countries` method.

The log is telling you that the method `name` does not exist for `nil`, which means that your object is `nil`.

Please show us the content of the "show_countries" method and please check that you have an acutal object given to the line of code responsible for the method `name` call.

Have you tried using a debugger ?

UPDATE:

Based on the `notice` code, your problem is that some post, does not have a coutry, then, `country_post.country` is `nil` which result to your error.

Either you ensure that you have a default country at the creation, or you do it in two step when trying to retrieve the information

```
if country_post.country.blank?
    countries << 'DEFAULT_COUNTRY_NAME'
else
    country << country_post.country.name
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @mrcasals most directly answers the question and will result in that exception no longer being raised.

However, a more "fundamental" problem here is that you are expecting some data to be persisted to the database which is not. Rails' canonical solution to the problem of ensuring the existence of attributes is via ActiveRecord validations. The general [overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) is a great read, and the [`presence` validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) should do the trick for this problem in particular.

Comment: You can't assume `self.country_post` is an array of ActiveRecord objects persisted to a database without more context of the app. That's why I didn't talk about validations, but you're right here.